# Azure database became readonly after deploying server to Azure

Tags: azure

I have got an SQL database on Azure.
When connecting to the DB from my Visual Studio, everything is fine. However, once I published the app to Azure, the database became read only. I can fetch the data, but cannot write anything. The server returns 500 code, but I did not any way of debugging it.
Could you advice of the solution?

Comment: Can you provide some more information on how you are deploying the Database? Is the Azure Database an Azure SQL, on a VM, or something else? In addition the 500 response a web response - it may not be because of the database.  Are you able to include the error message and/or exception?

Comment: The database should be OK. The server updates it successfully if I run the server locally. It's something to do with deploying the server onto Azure.
Even if I try to update a NON-Azure DB from Azure server it'll return the save error - 500 error code with a message "An error occurred"
Everything was fine when I deployed the server on another provider. It's just something wrong with Azure

Comment: An error occurred is a generic placeholder when the production is set to not emit errors.  Check the web server logs for exact details.  Are you updating the configuration correctly - connectionString etc?

Comment: @Kami , it doesn't give any specific information in the log except that an error occurred. The config is good. I repeat: if I run the server locally or upload to another hosting, it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the problem. 
I debugged the server remotely (luckily it is possible) and found out that the exception was thrown when trying to parse IP address (it is my code). Azure server has got ip:port and my code could only handle ip (without port). So I fixed it and it works.